# How to make a program that doubles letters (input = hello, returns = hheelllloo)

Tags: python

This is what i have so far - but it prints [tt],[tt,hh],[tt,hh,ee] when i input 'the'

```
def doubleChar(doubleit):
    doubled = []
    for letter in doubleit:
        doubled.append(letter * 2)
        print(doubled)

doubleChar('the')
```

Not a great attempt but couldn't really think of another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your print outside the loop, and also transform it back to string instead of a list of letters.

```
def doubleChar(doubleit):
    doubled = []
    for letter in doubleit:
        doubled.append(letter * 2)
    print("".join(doubled))

doubleChar('the')
```

Btw a function is not even needed, a simple one liner:

```
>>> r = "the"
>>> "".join(x*2 for x in r)
'tthhee'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a [zip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> def duplicator(s, n=2):
...     return ''.join(x for t in zip(*[s] * n) for x in t)
... 
>>> duplicator('the')
'tthhee'
>>> duplicator('potato', 3)
'pppoootttaaatttooo'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You just need to attach the different entries in the doubled list.

```
def doubleChar(doubleit):
  doubled = []
  for letter in doubleit:
    doubled.append(letter * 2)
  # at this stage you have ['tt', 'hh', 'ee'] 
  # you can join them into a str object
  return "".join(doubled)
```

You can also use a lambda combined with a comprehention to do it:

```
doubleChar = lambda s : "".join([e*2 for e in s])
```

Or you can keep your loop but use an str object without going through the list:

```
s = "the"
d = ""
for c in s:
  d = d + e*2
print(d)
>> 'tthhee'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is an unusual way using extended slicing

```
>>> s='the'
>>> (s+(' '+s*2)*len(s))[::len(s)+1]
'tthhee'
>>> s="hello world"
>>> (s+(' '+s*2)*len(s))[::len(s)+1]
'hheelllloo  wwoorrlldd'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda s, c: s + c + c, "hello", "")
```